# In C#, is there a way to force some properties to be initialized in object initializer?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

Consider the following code:

```
public class ClassA
{
    public int PropertyA { get; set; }
    public int PropertyB { get; set; }
}

// Somewhere else
var obj = new ClassA
{
    PropertyA = 1,
    // Question:
    // How do we force PropertyB to be set here without making it a parameter in the constructor?
    // Ideally in compile time so that the code here would cause a compile error.
};
```

Motivation: This question came to me when I tried to inject dependencies by properties instead of in constructors.

Comment: Make it part of a constructor, you can't do that with object initializer ( to my knowledge ) .

Comment: @Chris: That's what I tried to avoid. Injecting dependencies by constructor would cause a lot of problems when we want to add new dependencies. We have to add a new parameter to every constructor all the way along the dependency chain.

Comment: So you want to prevent [Temporal Coupling](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/24/DesignSmellTemporalCoupling/) but without atomic initialization? Hahaha... that's impossible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you don't realise this, but you can combine an object initialiser with a constructor.

So you can force initialisation in the constructor and still allow an object initialiser like so:

```
public class ClassA
{
    public ClassA(int propertyB)
    {
        PropertyB = propertyB;
    }

    public int PropertyA { get; set; }
    public int PropertyB { get; set; }
}
```

Hence:

```
var obj = new ClassA(2 /*Property B*/)
{
    PropertyA = 1
};
```

However, in answer to your question: No, you can't force a property to be initialised in an object initialiser.

Comment: That's what I tried to avoid. Injecting dependencies by constructor would cause a lot of problems when we want to add new dependencies. We have to add a new parameter to every constructor all the way along the dependency chain.

Comment: @ChrisXue Personally I'd always take constructor injection rather than property injection, if at all possible. If you use a property, surely you still need to pass it all the way along?