# Force a property initialization when initializing an object

Tags: c#, .net

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class User
{
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

User user = new User
{
    LastName = "Jane"
};
```

`FirstName` and `LastName` are required, why does the code let me initialize a user without `FirstName`? How can I force it so that `FirstName` must have a value as well?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In C#, is there a way to force some properties to be initialized in object initializer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33674187/in-c-is-there-a-way-to-force-some-properties-to-be-initialized-in-object-initi)

Answer (score 23):

[C# 11](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-11) introduces this new feature of being able to require a property when initializing an object with the [`required` keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/required).

You can do something like this:

```cs
public class User
{
    public required string FirstName { get; set; }
    public required string LastName { get; set; }
}

User user = new User
{
    FirstName = "Caffè",
    LastName = "Latte"
};
```

If you need the constructor, you need to add the `[SetsRequiredMembers]` attribute to it, like this:

```cs
public class User
{
    public required string FirstName { get; set; }
    public required string LastName { get; set; }

    [SetsRequiredMembers]
    public User(string firstName, string lastName) => (FirstName, LastName) = (firstName, lastName);
}

User user = new User("Caffè", "Latte");
```

Comment: Was this removed in C# 12+? The compiler doesn't seem to recognize it.

Answer (score 5):

You can add a constructor that forces you to initialize the property:

```
public class User
{
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public User(string firstName)
    {
       FirstName = firstName;
    }
}
```

This will be impossible:

```
User user = new User
{
    LastName = "Jane"
};
```

You'll have to do it like this:

```
User user = new User("something")
{
    LastName = "Jane"
};
```

Because you can still pass `null` to your constructor, you also might check this:

```
public User(string firstName)
        {
           if(firstName == null)
           {
              throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(firstName));
           }
           FirstName = firstName;
        }
```

Comment: But with a public `set` on that property, they can still set it to `null` afterwards...

Comment: The validation can also be done in the setter of the property, or it is possible to use nullable reference types.

Answer (score 2):

The `[Required]` attribute is used for model binding. If you require the class to have the FirstName property you should add a constructor.

```
public class User
{
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public User(string firstName)
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
    }
}

User user = new User("FirstName")
{
    LastName = "Jane"
};
```